# AngularJs filter parameter undefined

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-grid

I am using `Ui-grid` with cell dropdown edit functionality.
Problem is that i dont know why and how fix undefined `entity` variable in .filter.

I need to pass to filter data to change id keys to names.

```
var user = res.query({}, function(data) {   
        $scope.workers = data;
        $scope.gridOptions.data = data;
        $scope.gridOptions.columnDefs[3].editDropdownOptionsArray = data;       
        $scope.gridOptions.columnDefs[3].cellFilter ="griddropdown:data:'_id':'login':row.entity.parent"
 });
```

And some filter

```
.filter('griddropdown', function () {
    return function (input, entity, idField, valueField, initial) 

        console.log(entity);   // <--------- here entity is undefined 

        return 'DEF';
    };
});
```

template

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-sm-12">     
        <div ui-grid="gridOptions" class="myGrid" ui-grid-resize-columns ui-grid-move-columns ui-grid-edit ui-grid-cellNav></div>
    </div>
</div>
```

http://plnkr.co/edit/RC8sUwvjrNJqchzeBuA5?p=preview

Comment: could you please show how the template looks like?

Answer (score 0):

Seems like you are using `data` which doesn't exist in scope, you assigned it as JavaScript variable instead of define it in scope. I'd suggest you do use `$scope.gridOptions.columnDefs[3].editDropdownOptionsArray` on html so that get your code working.

Code

```
var user = res.query({}, function(data) {   
        $scope.workers = data;
        $scope.gridOptions.data = data;
        $scope.gridOptions.columnDefs[3].editDropdownOptionsArray = data;       
        $scope.gridOptions.columnDefs[3].cellFilter ="griddropdown: gridOptions.columnDefs[3].editDropdownOptionsArray :'_id':'login':row.entity.parent"
                                                                    //^^^^^^^^^^^^this will do the trick^^^^^^^^^^^^^
 });
```

Comment: i've added simplification of me work http://plnkr.co/edit/RC8sUwvjrNJqchzeBuA5?p=preview